# using multiple html forms to update mysql data using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

My code is given below (didn't include any html, no error/warning/notice). The program executes fine. The only problem I have is when I try to change the member_id and date fields in database- it doesn't work! As you can see I have used separate names for same fields mmid (used in the form) for member_id and dd (used in the form) for today. So, when user enters a different value it is assigned to mmid and dd while keeping the original values to member_id and dd allowing me to properly execute the update query. All other fields update is done as expected. None of the fields in the db is primary/unique/index. Could you please help me find where the problem is?

```
function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
// define variables and set to empty values
$memberErr = $employeeErr = $dateErr = $blankfieldErr ="";
$mmid = $dd = $member_id = $employee_id = $paid_installment = $savings_deposit = $late_fee = $today = $dayx = $monthx = $yearx = "";



if (isset($_POST['SubmitFirst']))
{
  if (empty($_POST["member_id"])) {
     $memberErr = "আপনি সদস্যর আইডি দিতে ভুলে গেছেন";
   } else {
     $member_id = test_input($_POST["member_id"]);
   }
    if(!empty($_POST["dayx"])) 
   {
     $dayx = test_input($_POST["dayx"]);
   }
   if(!empty($_POST["monthx"]))
   {
      $monthx = test_input($_POST["monthx"]);
   }
   if(!empty($_POST["yearx"])) // if all of them are selected
    {   
     $yearx = test_input($_POST["yearx"]);
    }
    if(!empty($_POST["dayx"]) and !empty($_POST["monthx"]) and !empty($_POST["yearx"])){
    $today= $yearx. "-" . $monthx. "-" . $dayx;  }
     else { $dateErr = "আপনি দিন / মাস / বছর লিখতে ভুলে গেছেন"; }
}

if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    echo $mmid;
echo " ";
echo $dd;
  if (empty($_POST["mmid"])) {
     $memberErr = "আপনি সদস্যর আইডি দিতে ভুলে গেছেন";
   } else {
     $mmid = test_input($_POST["mmid"]);
   }
  if (empty($_POST["dd"])) {
     $dateErr = "আপনি সদস্যর আইডি দিতে ভুলে গেছেন";
   } else {
     $dd = test_input($_POST["dd"]);
   } 

  if (empty($_POST["employee_id"])) {
     $employeeErr = "আপনি কর্মীর আইডি দিতে ভুলে গেছেন";
   } else {
     $employee_id = test_input($_POST["employee_id"]);
   }
  if (empty($_POST["paid_installment"]) and empty($_POST["savings_deposit"]) and empty($_POST["late_fee"])) {
     $blankfieldErr = "আপনি installment/savings/late_fee দিতে ভুলে গেছেন";
   } else {
     $paid_installment = test_input($_POST["paid_installment"]);
     $savings_deposit = test_input($_POST["savings_deposit"]);
     $late_fee = test_input($_POST["late_fee"]);
   }

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "yyyyy";
$dbname = "zzzzz";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// sql to UPDATE a record
$sql1 = "UPDATE daily_collection set date='$dd', member_id='$mmid', employee_id='$employee_id', paid_installment='$paid_installment', savings_deposit='$savings_deposit', late_fee='$late_fee' where member_id='$member_id' and date='$today'";

if ($result1=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1)) {
    echo "<h2>". "সাবাস আপনি ঠিকভাবে তথ্য রেকর্ড করেছেন!". "</h2>";
} else {
    echo "<h2>"."প্রোগ্রামে কিছু একটা সমস্যা হয়েছে, সুদিন স্যার-এর সাথে যোগাযোগ করুন ". "</h2>";
}

}


?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
   সদস্যর আইডি &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="member_id" value="<?php echo $member_id;?>" size="50">
   <span class="error"> <?php echo $memberErr;?></span>
   <br><br>

   তারিখ &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;দিন &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="dayx" value="<?php echo $dayx;?>" size="10"> &nbsp;&nbsp;মাস &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="monthx" value="<?php echo $monthx;?>" size="10"> &nbsp;&nbsp; বছর &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" name="yearx" value="<?php echo $yearx;?>" size="10">
<span class="error"> <?php echo $dateErr;?></span>   
   <br><br>
<center><input type="submit" name="SubmitFirst" value="SubmitFirst"></center><br>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['SubmitFirst']) and $member_id!="" and $today!="")
{ 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "yyyyy";
$dbname = "zzzzz";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql="select * from daily_collection where member_id='$member_id' and date='$today'";

if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
{
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
     $dd=$row["0"]; 
     $mmid=$row["1"];   
     $employee_id=$row["2"];
     $paid_installment=$row[3];
     $savings_deposit=$row[4];
     $late_fee=$row[5];
    }
    echo $member_id;
    echo " ";
echo $today;
}
else { echo "no such entry found";}
?>
<center><h2>দৈনিক কালেকশন এন্ট্রি ফর্ম</h2></center>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
   সদস্যর আইডি &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="mmid" value="<?php echo $mmid;?>" size="50">
   <span class="error"> <?php echo $memberErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   কর্মীর আইডি &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="employee_id" value="<?php echo $employee_id;?>" size="50">
   <span class="error"> <?php echo $employeeErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   কিস্তির টাকা &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="paid_installment" value="<?php echo $paid_installment;?>" size="50">
   <br><br>
   সঞ্চয় &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="savings_deposit" value="<?php echo  $savings_deposit;?>" size="50">
   <br><br>
   লেট ফী &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="late_fee" value="<?php echo $late_fee;?>" size="50">
   <span class="error"> <?php echo $blankfieldErr;?></span>      
   <br><br>
   তারিখ &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="dd" value="<?php echo $dd;?>" size="10">
<span class="error"> <?php echo $dateErr;?></span>   
   <br><br>
   <center><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></center><br>

</form>

<?php 
}



if(!empty($_POST['Submit']))
{ 

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
{` this block you have print `$mmid`, As `$mmid` is not set here so it will not print anything. To get the exact update query please echo `$sql1`

Update below part by

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
 $dd=$row["0"]; 
 $mmid=$row["1"];   
 $employee_id=$row["2"];
 $paid_installment=$row[3];
 $savings_deposit=$row[4];
 $late_fee=$row[5];
}


 **while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))** or instead of $row["0"] put $row[0] or exact column name like $row['date']
```

Comment: First thanks for replying. Actually, I used those echo for debugging, and yes, you are correct about it, they don't show the changed value. But that's not the problem. Problem is, all values change except for date and member_id in the database. Could u please see again?

Comment: Thank you so much! The problem has been resolved. But I had to pass $today and $member_id using html hidden input. It seems that the variables can't hold their values between form submits. Also, i had to assign them the values of $dd and $mmid right after the while loop. I couldn't have done this without you. Thanks again.

Comment: Did you check my updated reply? instead of using $row["0"] use specific column name. Try this `$dd=$row[0]; 
 $mmid=$row[1];   
 $employee_id=$row[2]`;

Comment: Yes, i did, but they give the same result, could you please tell me why it's better to use what you suggested?

Comment: there is no difference. instead of "_fetch_row" try to use "_fetch_assoc" & try to use the exact column name like $row["member_id"]

Comment: Thank you so much, i guess what you suggest is the good practice.

Comment: Also, could you please check my other question and help me about that?